# Paypal Merchant Rate pricing info via REST API

Tags: paypal, transactions, merchant-account

I looked over the documentation here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ but I'm still not finding the right request that will return what tier of Merchant Rate a particular user has.

For reference: Paypal can charge $.30/transaction and (2.7%, 2.5%, or 2.3%) of the dollar-value of a transaction. I'd like to request the current tier a particular merchant is being charged so I can run an estimated calculation on newly authorized or pending authorization transactions in my app before Paypal actually finishes processing and charging the fee.

The other option (more painful) is to run a reverse calculation on the most recently completed transaction* to identify the most recent fees being charged, then store that as the current tier and update it on a schedule.

Anyone tried to get this info or found a workaround successfully?

```
*example calculation
If the most recently completed gross transaction amount was 100, 
Fees charged were 3, net settlement was 97
Then 3.00 - .30 = $2.70
2.70/100 = .027
Therefore, current fee tier is 2.7 percent + .30
Then, I'd store that info.
```

Comment: p.s. apologies for the formatting on the example calculation -- site thought it was code and wouldn't let me post without formatting it as such.

Comment: There is no such API that PayPal provides to get the actual transaction rate for any account . I think you can continue with the way you are currently calculating the merchant rate .

Comment: Thanks Eshan, I was wondering if they would be open about it.